# Why are factor groups important?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why are factor groups important?

Thanks for your help

Comment: For one, it's a nice way to create new groups out of existing ones...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Among many other reasons:

1. Factor groups of $G$ capture all possible images of $G$ under homomorphisms (via the Isomorphism Theorems);
2. Factor groups of $G$ are "smaller" than $G$, so one may hope that they may be simpler to study than $G$ itself. The Isomorphism Theorems allow us to "import" a certain amount of information from factor groups to the groups themselves.
3. If you think of groups in terms of Galois Theory, with $G$ being the Galois group of a Galois field extension $K/F$, then the factor groups of $G$ corresponds precisely to the Galois groups of subextensions $E/F$, $E\subseteq K$, that are Galois over $F$.

Comment: Don't the factor groups correspond to the Galois groups of the subextensions K/E?

Comment: @JacobSchlather No they don't, $K/E$ is always a Galois extension whenever $K/F$ is.